# SSRS: weekOfYear

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have got this expression in my x-axis:

```
="W" & DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!Date.Value)
```

I would like to subtract with 1 the year 2016 because of the leap year
can I do something like this here:

```
="W" & iif(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear = "2015", Fields!Date.Value, iif(DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear = "2016", Fields!Date.Value)-1,) Fields!Date.Value))
```

I tried it with this code in my report:

```
Function getWeekNumber(ByVal d As DateTime) As Integer
    dim culture as System.Globalization.CultureInfo
    culture = system.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture

    dim weekRule as System.Globalization.CalendarWeekRule
    weekRule = culture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule

    dim firstDayOfWeek as System.DayOfWeek
    firstDayOfWeek = culture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek

    return culture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(d, weekRule, firstDayOfWeek)
End Function
```

But this shows me not the right weeknumber, the database is not from europe and I have got no possibility to change something in the database. How can I convert the weeknumber?

Comment: `="W" & iif(DatePart(DateInterval.Year) = "2016", DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!Date.Value) - 1, DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!Date.Value))`

Comment: this shows me a failure:  Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'DatePart' accepts this number of arguments.

Comment: `="W" & iif(DatePart(DateInterval.Year, Fields!Date.Value) = "2016", DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!Date.Value) - 1, DatePart(DateInterval.WeekOfYear, Fields!Date.Value))` you need to check the syntax.